# WEBrick: mount_proc

Tags: ruby, webrick, proc

What does the WEBrick instance method `mount_proc` do (in plain English)?

The docs say:

```
mount_proc(dir, proc=nil, &block) 
Mounts proc or block on dir and calls it with a WEBrick::HTTPRequest and WEBrick::HTTPResponse
```

but I'm not clear what `mounts proc on dir` actually means or does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mount_proc` allows you to specify a piece of code (a proc) that will be run when a request comes in. Here's a simple hello world example adapted [from the Ruby documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick.html)

```
require 'webrick'

server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new :Port => 8000
server.mount_proc '/' do |req, res|
  res.body = 'Hello, world!'
end

trap('INT') { server.stop } # stop server with Ctrl-C
server.start
```

now point your browser to `http://localhost:8000` and you should see

```
Hello, world!
```

Comment: OK, I'm clear what a `proc` is. What's `dir` in this context? And what does it mean by `mount proc on dir`?

Comment: `dir` is the request path. “Mount proc on dir” means that when you do `mount_proc '/foo'` the proc will be run when a request to `example.com/foo` is made.

Comment: Did this help you, or do you need additional info? If you've got more questions go ahead :-)